# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libjli.dylib , java image not found

Tags: java, macos, environment-variables

This is strictly for Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4

1. Tried setting environment variables in nano $HOME/.zshenv
2. this is what the path looks like export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk
3. Tried deleting JDK and then installing again, no success
4. I enter java --version into Terminal and get the error.
5. Error:
   dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libjli.dylib
   Referenced from: /Users/darianjennings/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/bin/java
   Reason: image not found
   zsh: abort      java --version

Answer (score 0):

Had to remove jdk folder from disk using the following commands.
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java

From there I had to re-install the .dmg file from Oracle.

Now when I type 'java --version' in Terminal I get the version type etc.
Then when I type 'which java' it shows 'usr/bin/java'

Not sure if I need to change my path in .zsh environment but I am getting a different error in Appium now:

'An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: could not sign with default certificate. Original error spawn ENOTDIR'